# RefreshMode.ClientWins or StoreWins

Tags: entity-framework

I have a simple windows form application using Entity Framework, and i'm stucked in this situation:

-User opens a windowsform (SearchForm) inside the MDIform, displaying products details and their actual stock qty.

-User opens a second windowsform (POSForm) inside the MDIform (alongside SearchForm), and after selling productos, the stock of that product is updated to the new quantity and saved to the DB, at this moment, the other opened winform (SearchForm) must updates the displayed data with the new data, i'm trying reloading the context, reinstantiating the context, refreshing the form, but the form still shows the same data..
I have an eventhandler in SearchForm, that fires when i call a method RefreshData() from POSForm, and try to refresh the data, but nothing seems to change.

Just after closing that form (SearchForm) and then open it again, the data is displayed correctly.

I don't know how to do a good refresh (i'm using context.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins,entry))

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you have a screen refresh / datasource refresh issue not an EF issue.
Write debug code to dump Context content to be sure.

Comment: thanks! yes, i just skipped to nominate the entry to refresh in this post!